# I don't understand this

Tags: area

"A plot is 60m long and 40m wide. A path 3m wide is to be constructed around the plot . find the area of the path"
This question is in my maths book and the answer is 636m square but I don't understand how

Comment: If the plot is a $60m$ by $40m$ rectangle, then the area of the plot is $2400m^2$. Do you mean the area of the path?

Comment: Hint: The total area of the plot and path is $66\times46$. The total area of just the plot is $60\times40$. The difference between the two numbers represents the area of the path.

Comment: Yeah we should find the area of the path

Comment: How did u get 66 and 46

Comment: We need to add lengthen each side by $3$m on each end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$636 = [(60+2\times 3) \times (40 + 2\times 3)] - (60\times 40) $$

That is, the area that is added to the plot after paving a path around plot that is  $3$ meters wide is equal to $636$ m$^2$: the area of the new 3m wide path surrounding the original plot.

Comment: Why did you multiply by 2 though

Comment: @yomna: There's 3 m of path north of the plot and another 3 m of path south of it.

Comment: I get it! Thank you @HenningMakholm

Comment: I get it! Thank you @wckronholm

Comment: I get it! Thank you @amWhy

Comment: You're welcome, yomna!